# regular expression to match one dot or three dot validator

Tags: javascript, regex

In the field want to allow one dot or three dot

For three dot my regex is this it working

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+[.]{3}$/
```

But i try for one and three both it does not work. I try it with | (or) sign

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+[.]{1})|([a-zA-Z]+[.]{3})$/
```

Thanks in advance

Thanks again its working But i want to allow below options

Means 1 0r 3 dot any where in word but not 2,4,5 dot.

```
1) M.C.A
2) M.C.A...
3) M...CA.
```

Below regex works for above requirement

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+(\.|\.\.\.)([a-zA-z]+)?)+$/
```

Comment: try \. for a single dot...

Comment: @janakshah Won't change anything, `[.]` is just a *nice way* (IMO) to escape a dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just simplify the or statement into one group, for example

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(\.|\.\.\.)$
```

This will match any number of characters ending with either a `.` or `...`

Comment: Thanks again its working But i want to allow below options 

Means 1 0r 3 dot any where in word but not 2,4,5 dot.
 
    1) M.C.A
    2) M.C.A...
    3) M...CA.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There might be easier ways of doing what you require.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+[.](?:[.]{2})?$/
```

Means, match one dot and optionally two more.

`(?:[.]{2})?` is an non capturing group (because of `?:`) that is optional because of the `?` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the alternation is wrong (the start-of-string anchor only affects the first alternation, the end-of-string anchor only the second):

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+[.]{1})   |   ([a-zA-Z]+[.]{3})$/
```

Change the parentheses to make sure both anchors are bound to both the alternations:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+[.]{1}|[a-zA-Z]+[.]{3})$/
```

or, even better, without any alternation:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+\.(\.{2})?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced `|`.You are trying to match text that starts with `([a-zA-Z]+[.]{1})` or that ends with `([a-zA-Z]+[.]{3})`

Correct regex is

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+([.]{3}|[.])$/
```